# Profiling .NET application from cmd: missing vsperf.exe for x64

Tags: .net, windows, profiling, remote-debugging

I'm trying to profiling a .NET 4.5 application on Windows 2008 R2 x64 remotely.
I installed the vs_profiler_x64_enu.exe (taken from the VS 2015) and run the VSPerfCmd.exe from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64 folder. It says:

> Error VSP1336: Could not attach to process ID:... w3wp.exe. To
>   collect sampling data on this version of Windows, use vsperf.exe

Not sure what's wrong with my Windows version, but say. The problem that the are no vsperf.exe in the x64 directory, but it exists in the parent directory which is intended for x86 applications. Running it anyway returns the expected error:

> Error VSP1336: Could not attach to process ID:... w3wp.exe.
>   Profiling 64-bit processes is not supported by this version of the
>   profiling tools. Please use the profiling tools from the x64
>   directory.

Googling didn't help. According to everything I found the \x64\vsperf.exe should exists. Installing the Remote Tools (rtools_setup_x64.exe) also did't help.

Comment: did you try to attach to another process or may be a different 32 bit w3wp?

Comment: Profiling 32 bit process using the vsperf for x86 seems works. Problem with x64

Comment: Same problem trying to profile a large x64 application..
Where is `x64\vsperf.exe` ?